# PessimisticLockException while using Spring @Transactional

Tags: transactional, pessimistic-locking

I have a requirement in which I need to modify a field in 6 tables, and need to do that in single transaction.

So I used spring @Transactional (with default settings) for it.

Now, while fetching and updating data within transactional method, if any other call tries to access one of the table (Event), my application gets hanged due to possible lock on Event table, and in application logs, I get *javax.persistence.PessimisticLockException*.

What I want is that while executing *@Transactional* method, application should serve all read requests made to database, and should not get hanged due to lock.

Note:
I am using derby database in Embedded mode.
Things are working fine with MySql.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Request to please provide some assistance on issue.

Comment: Can anyone please provide some help. Anticipating for some response.